# AndroidNetworking lib not logging anything

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm trying to reach an API with [AndroidNetworking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) lib.

**Here is how I initalized it:**

```
public class TestLabApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    //For logging
    RealInterceptor realInterceptor = new RealInterceptor();
    realInterceptor.enableLoggingForBody(true);
    realInterceptor.enableLoggingForUrl(true);
    realInterceptor.enableLoggingForHeaders(true);
    realInterceptor.enableLoggingForHttpStatusCodes(true);
    realInterceptor.enableLoggingForExecutionTime(false);

    //Add logging to okHttpClient
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(realInterceptor)
            .build();

    //Init AndroidNetworking lib with the okHttpClient (with aloggint interceptor)
    AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext(), okHttpClient);

}
}
```

**I've added this to the manifest too:**

```
 <application
        android:name=".TestLabApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**This is my own interceptor, because the one in the doc's example is simply not part of the lib.**

```
public class RealInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private boolean logUrl             = true;
private boolean logBody            = true;
private boolean logHeaders         = true;
private boolean logHttpStatusCodes = true;
private boolean logExecutionTime   = true;


public void enableLoggingForUrl(boolean logUrl) {
    this.logUrl = logUrl;
}

public void enableLoggingForHeaders(boolean logHeaders) {
    this.logHeaders = logHeaders;
}

public void enableLoggingForBody(boolean logBody) {
    this.logBody = logBody;
}

public void enableLoggingForHttpStatusCodes(boolean logHttpStatusCodes) {
    this.logHttpStatusCodes = logHttpStatusCodes;
}

public void enableLoggingForExecutionTime(boolean logExecutionTime) {
    this.logExecutionTime = logExecutionTime;
}


private void logInfo(Object o) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), o.toString());
}

private void logError(Object o) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), o.toString());
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Request     request        = chain.request();
    RequestBody requestBody    = request.body();
    boolean     hasRequestBody = requestBody != null;


    if (logUrl) {
        sb.append("\nURL: " + request.url());
    }

    if (logBody) {
        if (hasRequestBody) {
            Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            requestBody.writeTo(buffer);
            String bodyParams = buffer.readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            bodyParams = bodyParams.replace("&", "\nParam: ");

            sb.append("\nParam: " + bodyParams);
        } else {
            sb.append("\nParam: <No params>");
        }
    }


    if (logHeaders) {
        Headers headers    = request.headers();
        String  headersStr = "";
        for (int i = 0, count = headers.size(); i < count; i++) {
            headersStr += "\nHeader: " + headers.name(i) + ": " + headers.value(i);
        }
        sb.append(headersStr);
    }

    long     startNs = System.nanoTime();
    Response response;
    try {
        response = chain.proceed(request);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    if (logHttpStatusCodes) {
        sb.append("\nHTTP Status code: " + response.code());
    }

    long tookSec = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(System.nanoTime() - startNs);
    long tookMs  = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startNs);

    if (logExecutionTime) {
        if (tookSec > 1) {
            sb.append("\nExecution time: " + tookSec + " sec");
        } else {
            sb.append("\nExecution time: " + tookMs + " ms");
        }
    }

    if (response.code() != 200) {
        logError(sb.toString());
    } else {
        logInfo(sb.toString());
    }


    return response;
}
```

}

**How I'm trying to use it:**

```
AndroidNetworking.post("http://myurlishere.hu/api/test-result/save")
                    .addBodyParameter("param_1", "12345")
                    .addBodyParameter("param_2", "abcdef")
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // do anything with response

                            Log.i("RESP___", response.toString());

                            codeTv.setText(getString(R.string.please_read_the_qr_code));

                            enableControls(true);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            zBarScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "API done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError error) {
                            // handle error

                            codeTv.setText(getString(R.string.please_read_the_qr_code));
                            enableControls(true);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            zBarScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);


                            DialogHelper.showInfo(MainActivity.this, "Error: Body: "+error.getErrorBody()+", Response: "+error.getResponse()+", Detail: "+error.getErrorDetail()+", Code: "+error.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    });
```

**The problem is:**

**I don't see ANY logs about what is happening. Why?**

Comment: I [*do* see logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IteU9.png). Seems like a misconfiguration in Android Studio.

Comment: https://blog.codavel.com/how-to-create-an-http-interceptor-for-an-android-app-using-okhttp3   hope this will help you

Comment: You might use https://github.com/orhanobut/logger for logging instead. Your code doesn't look that off actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but I can suggest alternative solution for logging

Firstly it is not necessary to create your own logging, As already `package okhttp3.logging`  Provides `HttpLoggingInterceptor` which does log all the values which you expected in your `RealInterceptor`.

Here is an alternative solution :

```
   val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            okHttpClientBuilder!!.addInterceptor(logging)
```

In your case :

```
  //Add logging to okHttpClient
    var okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
                .build()
```

Hope this helps, in case release mode of the application you can disable logging by just adding condition:

```
    var okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient()
                       .newBuilder()

     if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            okHttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
      }

     var okHttpClient = okHttpClientBuilder.build()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### Network Interceptors
>
> - Able to operate on intermediate responses like redirects and retries.
> - Not invoked for cached responses that short-circuit the network.
> - Observe the data just as it will be transmitted over the network.
> - Access to the Connection that carries the request.

I think your request have a cache and `NetworkInterceptor` will not working. Try to use `addInterceptor` instead of `addNetworkInterceptor`. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be lacking a no-args constructor, as the `new` keyword requires it:

```
public RealInterceptor() {}
```

Try to add it and it should return an instance. But better switch to Retrofit2 from some obviously abandoned library with roughly 200 open issues; there you can use the same `Interceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understood as to why you are implementing `Interceptor` and making your own implementation of the `Interceptor`? Like do you need some custom logging features that is not provided in the library itself?

If all you need is to log headers and/or body of the request/response, the `README` file mentions that you can do so by simply enabling Logging.

```
AndroidNetworking.enableLogging(); // simply enable logging
AndroidNetworking.enableLogging(LEVEL.HEADERS); // enabling logging with level
```

It seems there are different levels that you can provide:

```
public enum Level {
        /**
         * No logs.
         */
        NONE,
        /**
         * Logs request and response lines.
         * <p>
         * <p>Example:
         * <pre>{@code
         * --> POST /greeting http/1.1 (3-byte body)
         *
         * <-- 200 OK (22ms, 6-byte body)
         * }</pre>
         */
        BASIC,
        /**
         * Logs request and response lines and their respective headers.
         * <p>
         * <p>Example:
         * <pre>{@code
         * --> POST /greeting http/1.1
         * Host: example.com
         * Content-Type: plain/text
         * Content-Length: 3
         * --> END POST
         *
         * <-- 200 OK (22ms)
         * Content-Type: plain/text
         * Content-Length: 6
         * <-- END HTTP
         * }</pre>
         */
        HEADERS,
        /**
         * Logs request and response lines and their respective headers and bodies (if present).
         * <p>
         * <p>Example:
         * <pre>{@code
         * --> POST /greeting http/1.1
         * Host: example.com
         * Content-Type: plain/text
         * Content-Length: 3
         *
         * Hi?
         * --> END POST
         *
         * <-- 200 OK (22ms)
         * Content-Type: plain/text
         * Content-Length: 6
         *
         * Hello!
         * <-- END HTTP
         * }</pre>
         */
        BODY
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you. Have a nice one :)